# Why NO ModuleNotFoundError with conda?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, miniconda, python-importlib

Normally when I've done `pip uninstall <module>` if I then try to import the module I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`, for example:

```py
dino@DINO:~$ python -c 'import mplfinance as mpf;print(mpf.__file__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mplfinance'
```

However, after activating a conda environment, the import works fine ***even when the package is unstalled both with `pip uninstall` and with `conda remove`***, either way, I get:

```py
dino@DINO:~$ python -c 'import mplfinance as mpf;print(mpf.__file__)'
None
```

Can anyone tell me ***why*** the **import** is ***NOT raising an exception***, even though there is no module there to import??
This behavior (lack of import exception) *appears* to be related somehow to having activated a conda environment.